# How to call ${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message} in a jsp scriptlet?

Tags: jsp, scriptlet

I have to remove jstl library (license issues). What is the correct way to re-write `<c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}"/>` using a jsp scriptlet?

I tried the below code among several others:

```
<%= session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message") %>
```

but it returns null.

Also, I cannot simply change to `${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}` because all special html characters need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION is a session attribute in which a spring exception has been stored so you must access it as following:

```
<%= session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION").getMessage() %>
```

**SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION** represents an exception and message is one of its properties.

**EDIT:**

`<%= ((AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException)session.getAttr‌​ibute("SPRING_SECURI‌​TY_LAST_EXCEPTION"))‌​.getMessage() %>` worked. Of course, I had to import AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException

Comment: I tried it, but I get "The method getMessage() is undefined for the type Object" error. I tried casting it to String, but I get a similar error message

Comment: <%= ((AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException)session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION")).getMessage() %> worked. Of course, I had to import AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException